# How to take screenshot of a website with Rails 3.1? -- without using a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

Almost every answer I've found references using some existing service. **Is there a way to do this using Rails 3.1 programmatically?** This was dead easy to do with PHP (there are prebuilt libraries in PHP that do this).

What I'm looking to do, given a URL, is:

1. Take a screenshot of the website
2. Crop it (only take the top left most 100x100 pixels

PS. Here is my environment: Rails **3.1**, Ruby **1.9.2**

**Note:** The solution would probably need to follow any redirections on the URL as well.

**Updates:**

- I've seen https://github.com/topfunky/osxscreenshot The problem is that it requires an older version of Ruby (1.8.x) and will only work on my dev Mac machine.
- I've seen the vulnerability with Wordpress (they have a service that doesn't do any rate limiting which someone could potentially abuse). I would not want to abuse their resources for my benefit... http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F?w=500
- The cropping will be easy with http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/ or https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Answer (score 8):

There is a Rails gem for this task.

```
 gem install selenium-webdriver
```

Simple use case:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
 width = 1024
 height = 728
 driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
 driver.navigate.to 'http://domain.com'
 driver.execute_script %Q{
   window.resizeTo(#{width}, #{height});
 }
 driver.save_screenshot('/tmp/screenshot.png')
 driver.quit
```

Comment: Clever solution, though I think it needs to be installed on a client with those browsers installed as I had trouble server side doing this.

Comment: Note that execute_script part should be replaced with `driver.manage.window.resize_to(width,height)`

Comment: This works thx! But how can I do to execute same script on my linux  server (without browser)?

Answer (score 4):

This might help: https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit

Comment: It's dependent on wkhtmltoimage which is not available for many platforms (including Mac)

Comment: wkhtmltoimage is available on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You could use wkhtmltoimage to load up the webpage and save it as an image, then imagemagick, (or one of the ruby wrappers for it) to crop it.

```
wkhtmltoimage www.google.com output.jpg
convert -crop 100x100+0+100 output.jpg cropped.jpg
```

There isn't a prebuilt wkhtmltoimage binary for OSX though, so perhaps you may want to use wkhtmltopdf instead and then imagemagick to convert to an image.

```
wkthmltopdf www.google.com output.pdf
convert -crop 100x100+0+100 output.pdf cropped.jpg
```

Comment: The rendering of wkthmltopdf appears to bad for most sites :( Otherwise this would have been the way to go.

Comment: @user1049097 I've never had a problem with it. Maybe you don't have enough fonts or a QT-enabled build.

Comment: I'm going to try this again on mac and see if I'm missing any fonts, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple, **but Mac only**, solution seems to be http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/

Just `chmod -x` that script and use as `python webkit2png http://www.google.com/` and it creates 3 files:

1. Full screenshot
2. Thumbnail of the top most portion of site
3. Thumbnail of the full screenshot