# Given a url, how do i print the screenshot of that site using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, screenshot

How can i get a screenshot given a URL in rails?

Is there a gem that would help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218501/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-website-with-rails-3-1-without-using-a-service

Comment: this is not a rails question at all.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel well...but I still stuck in this problem, and have no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get the screenshots from capybara.

https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#manual-screenshots